# Nginx redirect issue - gives 403

Tags: apache, redirect, nginx, url-rewriting

Have Nginx proxying to Apache. But for one domain, I don't want to call in Apache at all. Just want to forward this domain to another domain (parent domain).

This is my `/etc/nginx/vhost/child.com` code:

```
server {
  server_name child.com www.child.com;
  rewrite ^ http://www.parentdomain.com$request_uri? permanent;
}
```

But when I do `curl -I child.com`, I see this:

```
  HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
  Server: Domo Hosting 
  Date: Wed, 06 Aug 2014 13:34:21 GMT
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
  Connection: keep-alive
  Vary: Accept-Encoding
  Content-Length: 321
```

What am I doing wrong? All the other Nginx domains are working as desired, and Apache/Nginx play well together.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to add a "listen" directive.

```
listen <IPADDRESS>:80;
```

Without this, Nginx doesn't know it should listen on the port and IP address, therefore your vhost isn't doing anything at the moment.

Comment: Thank you. This fixes the 403 and makes it a 200: it just shows the Nginx's default "It Works!"  What now. What can I do in Nginx to truly forward a domain to another?

Comment: I think you have another vhost active, maybe the default vhost? Apparently that vhost matches better than this one. You could try to disable that one and see if it works. Or you could try to find out why the other vhost matches better than this one.

Comment: This is a standard Nginx setup where `/etc/nginx/vhosts` has multiple domains. Each domain is a file by itself and inside the file for each domain is a `server_name` directive. No other file in this directory has a server_name for this domain. So I doubt any other vhost is being picked up specifically for this domain. Or am I missing something?

Comment: OK I solved it. The "Listen" needs an IP and a port. I had only a port as shown in some examples on the web. Thanks!

Comment: That's great. Virtualhosts get matched first on IP address, then on server_name. That's probably why another virtualhost matched better than this one.